# Windows 10 New Snip & Sketch Tool notification missing

Tags: windows-10, action-center, snipping-tool

When I installed the latest Windows 10 update I really liked the new screenshot / clipping tool that you can access with WIN+SHIFT+S.

Then after some time each time I use it the snipped picture gets copied to my clipboard, but the notification is missing and also there is no notification  available in the Action Center, so I can not edit the snipped picture (sketch) in any way.

Is there a solution?

Comment: If it's get copied to clipboard you can paste it in MSPaint then edit or save it there.

Comment: I know I can. But that was not my question - I would like to have the intended functionality back

Comment: Go to Start, Settings, Apps.  Scroll down to Snip and Sketch.  Click in Advanced Options.  Then click on Reset to repair / reset the App.  Close out, restart and test.  If necessary, uninstall it and reinstall from the Store.

Comment: Experience exact the same issue. Even doing nothing it starts working and later it stops working and later then it is working again and so on...

Comment: Windows update broke mine. FIX: Uninstall both apps 1) Snipping Tool, and 2) Snip & Sketch. Reboot if prompted.  Go to Microsoft and download snipping tool. (I tired direct download from website, it doesn't work). Even though it says Snipping tool in the title, it will install Snip & Sketch (no reboot). Then windows + shift + s

Answer (score 33):

Had this happen to me in the last few days - tried the various options above, to no avail

Turns out it was just the App itself

(Which apparently https://superuser.com/users/1079976/john answered in a comment to the original question...my bad, missed it until after I'd typed this up)

1. Went to Settings
2. Apps & features
3. Search/scroll for "Snip & Sketch"
4. Click to expand
5. Select Advanced options
6. Click the Reset button

[Settings - Apps & features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7dFD.png)

[Reset button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyUp4.png)

Comment: This worked for me

Comment: Oh wow, this worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Weird. I have no "Snip & Skech" in the app list, even it is there/working (sometimes)...

Answer (score 16):

Had the same problem worked fine for several weeks, then suddenly no more popups.

This fixed it for me:

- Right click on the notfication center icon in the taskbar
- Focus Assist
- switch to Off (was set to 'Alarms only')

Comment: in the meantime I did a complete reinstall of the system (because of other issues) and since then it worked. If it stops working again, I'll try your solution. Best

Comment: I don't know why MS keep messing about with our settings when they come up with something new. Thanks for this solution!

Comment: Had notifications enabled, everything else looked good. This is what fixed it for me. Thank you!

Comment: @Reinhard you Sir are a legend !

Comment: OMG, that worked! I forgot I had that on because NOTHING ELSE HONOURS IT!

Answer (score 12):

To enable notifications from the Snip & Sketch Tool:

- Start Settings
- Click on System
- Click on Notif‌ications & actions
- Find Snip & Sketch and set it to On

Comment: It's set to ON and doesnt work

Comment: That's not normal. Try to check Windows using [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Done; I get this: Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

Comment: Maybe a registry change. For comparison, I posted my registry entry for [Snipping Tool reg file](https://pastebin.com/iVQ2hanF) for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\TabletPC\Snipping Tool`.

Comment: I think my setting are OK:
AutoCopyToClipboard: 0x1
CaptureMode: 0x2
CapturePenColor: 0xff
CaptureWindowVisible: 0x1
CustomPenColor: 0xff0000
CustomPenThickness: 0x40000000
CustomPenTip: 0x1
DisplaySnipInstructions: 0x1
DisplayURL: 0x1
FileFormat: 0
MarkupPen: 0x1
NotFirstRun: 0x1
PromptToSave: 0x1
SendTo: 0
ShowCaptureStroke: 0
ToolbarX: 0x8c
ToolbarY: 0x45e
IsScreenSketchBannerExpanded: 0x1

Comment: They seem similar enough. Do you see this notification if you open the Action Center (Win+A)?

Comment: No, action center is completely empty

Comment: Maybe you should uninstall it (right-click in the Start menu) and re-install from the Microsoft Store. Create a System Restore save before starting, just in case.

Comment: So, I did an uninstall, but it doesnt uninstall completely (link in Start menu remains). Then I wanted to reinstall from Store, but I cannot: error 0x80070005.

Comment: You may find some solutions [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/microsoft-store-error-0x80070005/afc0f6d0-9632-4610-886a-494f7288fb42). If nothing works, restore the System Restore save to return to the previous situation.

Comment: I get stuck at 3. Run Windows Store Apps Troubleshooter. It finds some error, but it can not fix it. So all I get is to send a report to MS.. :(

Comment: 1, 2 and 4 dont help. I didnt try 5 and the rest.

Comment: Better rollback to the saved System Restore point. If the problem is really bothering you, a heavy procedure such as [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) might help bring the notifications back. This is equivalent to doing the 1903 Windows update again, so take the same precautions.

Comment: OK, thank you for the help

Comment: I've seen this solution in a lot of sites, but my problem is that Snip and sketch app just doesn't show in this list. Not even after resetting the app.

Answer (score 10):

Just throwing in my experience, looks like I had deliberately switched off notifications (on a global level), which unintentionally includes Snip & Sketch. The app was installed properly and such.

To quickly enable this right click the notifications icon/button in your taskbar then choose **Turn on notifications**:

[image: Taskbar > Turn on notifications]

Or open **Windows Settings** (press **WIN+I**), choose **System**, then **Notifications & actions** in the sidebar. There is a global toggle for notifications here to turn on.

[image: Windows Settings > System > Notifications & Actions]

Comment: I had this problem on Windows 11 and this is the fixed I used. The navigation on Windows 11 is a little different, once in the Settings app you need to navigate to **System > Notifications** and then make sure it is turned on. Under the "Notifications from apps and other senders" section also make sure Snipping Tool is set to On and it says **"Banners"** underneath the app icon. If it does not say "Banners" underneath the app icon, click the arrow next to the On toggle and turn on banners from the next page.

Comment: how did it got disabled in first place? any idea? i was able to fix it like this.

Comment: As per my answer: "I had deliberately switched off notifications (on a global level)".

Answer (score 9):

I got the same problem.

My issue was because the Snip and Sketch tool was not installed on my Windows.

The `Win + Shift + S` shortcut works without it, but it only copy the scrot to the clipboard.

If you want to have the editing features (with includes the notifications) you have to install Snip and Sketch from the Microsoft Store:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/snip-sketch/9mz95kl8mr0l

Comment: I spent so much time "wasted" on the other solutions.. So simple a fix. My boxstarter script removed ALL non required windows apps on first boot I would have never found this solution without you. Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you! that was it for me.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually explorer.exe not working properly. If you restart it through the Task Manager it goes back to normal.

Comment: I restarted the explorer but it didn't help :(

Answer (score 1):

There are some things you could try before reinstalling Windows 10:

1. Check if you turned **Focus Assist** on
2. Check if some weird "system cleaning" software deletes Snip & Sketch
3. (Requires restart) Reset Notification settings in registry

## Check if Focus Assist is turned on

This is the most common case for the Snip & Sketch notification missing. Check the Action Centre on the bottom right corner of your screen. If there is a moon icon, then you have Focus Assist on. Simply right click, then you could turn it off in the pop-up menu.

## Check if some weird "system cleaning" software deletes Snip & Sketch

This is the most common case for the missing notification if you are from Mainland China, as there are tons of PC manager software, or （某大数字60、某讯之类的）电脑管家, awaiting the chance of messing up your PC :)

Press Win+X then select Windows PowerShell, then type:

```
> Get-AppxPackage | select-string screensketch
```

Normally it would return a line reporting Snip & Sketch's package full name, like this:

```
Microsoft.ScreenSketch_10.2008.2277.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

If it is returning an empty line, then simply go to [the store page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/snip-sketch/9mz95kl8mr0l), and download the Snip tool back.

## Reset Notification Registry

Open regedit, then delete everything under `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App`. Don't forget to restart your machine!

Answer (score 0):

I tried resetting the Snip & Sketch app, or uninstalling and reinstalling it, with no success. Keyboard shortcut didn't work, and if I manually started the app, it complained about a missing ms-screenclip association.

Finally fixed it by executing the following line in a Powershell:

`Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}`

Not sure what it's doing, looks like it forces all packages to re-register with the system, but after executing it, Snip & sketch works again (even its keyboard shortcut), and it also shows in *Notifications and actions* screen, something it didn't happen before.