# my snip and sketch notifications are gone (suddenly)

Tags: windows-10, snipping-tool

One day, I tried to capture with snip and sketch but I don't get the on-screen banner or action center notifications.
I tried to turn it on in "Get notifications from senders" but the snip and sketch thing wasn't even there.
I'm pretty sure because there was only 6 items to turn on.
I tried different methods from the Internet but none of them worked.
Send help.

Comment: What did you try?  DISM ?

Comment: I tried sfc/scannow with cmd as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Try to press on the small notification icon and see if it's there.

If it is there, then you should disable "work hours" in settings, such as that windows won't mute notification ( aka "focus assist" ). Here's a guide: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-off-notifications-in-windows-during-certain-times-81ed1b25-809b-741d-549c-7696474d15d3#ID0EDD=Windows_10

I'd you do not see the snip, then change the setting in "snip and sketch" settings, like here [Windows 10 New Snip & Sketch Tool notification missing](https://superuser.com/questions/1487153/windows-10-new-snip-sketch-tool-notification-missing)

Comment: I'm sure that i do not have "focus assist" turned on because i checked it (its off)
Also, I did reset my snip and sketch settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyUp4.png but nothing helped.
For "Get notifications from senders" I turned the notifications on. Scrolled down, there isn't even the choice for snip and sketch... 
https://imgur.com/a/STNt9Vx
https://imgur.com/a/ciDUT27
Someone said that was abnormal, and i did sfc/scannow in cmd as an admin and restarted computer.
I also updated my snipping tool in the microsoft store but that still didnt help.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/1FcXMF9
Somebody said resetting the notification registry would help.
when i tried to do this step by step, 
I first found HKEY_CURRENT USER but i saw microsoft instead of SOFTWARE secondly.
and then i chose Windows - CurrentVersion and then Notifications weren't there...
`\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App`
It was really strange and I don't know how to solve this problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since the basic repair did not work, then next step is a Windows 10 Repair Install.

Since DISM / SFC did not work, then next step is a Windows 10 Repair install.

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair. Proceed normally answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything. Keep Everything does just that and is not a fresh install.

The Keep Everything repair often works. If not, it normally means the User Profile is damaged or the operating system is seriously damaged.

In either case, the best solution is to back up and reinstall Windows.

**Follow up:**

You said your computer is 6 years old. You can easily reinstall Windows if the computer is in good shape otherwise. However at 6 years old, it will not run Windows 11.

It may be time to replace the computer with a Windows 11 computer.

Comment: To do what you mentioned, I had to run my computer as an administrator.
And to run my computer as an administrator, I had to change my local account into an administrator.
Which I can't.  https://imgur.com/a/rHd4oWw
I don't have the Friends and Other Users option.
Well, I guess this computer is rusty after 6 years...

Comment: Make another account and make it a member of administrators.  That should work. If not then you need to reinstall Windows which is the last option in my post.  6 years old (computer) is not too old to do this.

Comment: I also added the possibility of replacing the computer with a Windows 11 computer.

Comment: Can you list the consequences of reinstalling Windows?
This computer was owned by one of my family members but he now no longer uses it.
He also stored his own stuff here.

Comment: If a Repair Keep Everything works - then no consequences.  If it does not work, then back up  and reinstall means the data for the family member will be in the backup drive.  That is normal.

Comment: Sorry for not following your instruction that I asked for.
It sounds like too much efforts for me.
I guess I'll just buy a new computer next year.
Thanks for all the hard work and help.

Comment: You may wish to accept my answer then, as that was one of my suggestions.